# Compilation failure with maven - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project forked and cloned from a git repo, i run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Return compile error:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /home/weverton/projetos/trivia/trivia-solver/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/weverton/projetos/trivia/trivia-solver/src/main/java/ru/thevalidator/galaxytriviasolver/module/base/impl/GalaxyBaseRobotImpl.java:[56,68] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SolverImpl
  location: package ru.thevalidator.galaxytriviasolver.module.trivia.solver.impl
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.001 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-22T13:51:30-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project galaxy-trivia-solver: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/weverton/projetos/trivia/trivia-solver/src/main/java/ru/thevalidator/galaxytriviasolver/module/base/impl/GalaxyBaseRobotImpl.java:[56,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SolverImpl
[ERROR]   location: package ru.thevalidator.galaxytriviasolver.module.trivia.solver.impl
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

[image: screenshot my code - 1]
[image: screenshot my code - 2]

Obs: I'm a beginner with java and I'm learning, can someone help me understand so I can solve this problem?

Comment: help me understand so I can solve this problem

Comment: @K.Nicholas , I downloaded this repository from github and I'm trying to run it, but the return is this error, apparently the `SolverImpl.java` class does not exist in the mentioned directory: `/trivia/trivia-solver/src/main/java/ru/thevalidator/galaxytriviasolver/module/trivia/solver/impl`, but there is another file called `SolverRestImpl.java`

Comment: ru.thevalidator.galaxytriviasolver.module.trivia.solver.impl.SolverImpl is missing from the classpath. It should be source or in a dependency jar. What is the url of the github repo and I will take a look?